# Problema al evaluar modelo arbol de decisión - party

Tags: r

Construí un árbol de decisión con party usando el siguiente código:

```
# Cargar datos
library(readxl)
Ingresantes <- read_excel("Ingresantes_Sin56copia.xlsx")
View(Ingresantes)

# Cargar libreria 
install.packages("party")
library(party)

# Formar dos conjuntos: datos de entrenamiento (70%) y datos de prueba (30%)
set.seed(1234)
ind<-sample(2,nrow(Ingresantes),replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.7,0.3))
traindata<-Ingresantes[ind==1,]
testdata<-Ingresantes[ind==2,]

#Ingresantes$estado01 <- as.factor(Ingresantes$estado01)
# CON FORMULA 4:
#myFormula <- estado01 ~ Carrera + Regulares + esMujer+ Edad  + TipoDeColeg+ 
#EstMadreR 

# Ajustar el modelo con datos de entrenamiento
modelo_party <- ctree(estado01~., data=traindata)

# Imprimir Reglas del árbol 
print(modelo_party) 

# Graficar árbol
#plot(mydata_ctree) # complicado de interpretar
plot(modelo_party,type="simple")   # mejor, más simple de interpretar   

# EVALUAR MODELO
predicciones <- predict(modelo_party, testdata,type="response")
mean(predicciones == testdata$estado01) # RESULTADOo= 0 ¿¿???

# Observar dónde se cometió error
table(predicciones,testdata$estado01)

# Matriz de Confusion
install.packages("caret")
library(caret)
confusionMatrix(table(predicciones,testdata[["estado01"]])) # Obtener matriz 
de confusión
```

El problema se presenta al EVALUAR EL MODELO, como resultado de mean() me da CERO!, no creo que sea tan malo el modelo o si?. Estoy aplicando bien??. cuando llego a la línea de "Observar error" me muestra la tabla:
[image: Tabla Obtenida]

Que no tendría que ser sólo 0,1 como columna 1, ya que la variable 'estado01' toma solo valores 0 ó 1???, qué hago mal???.
Intenté crear la matriz de confusión con Caret y peor!. Me sale el siguiente mensaje: "Error in !all.equal(nrow(data), ncol(data)) : invalid argument type".
Evidentemente estoy haciendo mal las cosas pero no tengo ni idea dónde. Por favor si alguien me orienta?????.

**Agrego información sobre objetos:**
[image: Información de objetos]
Saludos

Comment: Claudia, agrega información de los objetos que estás comparando `str(predicciones )` y `str(testdata$estado01)`

Comment: Patricio, no entendí lo que me indicas :(

Comment: Lo que te decía es que ejecutes los comandos anteriores y agregas lo que te muestran en el cuerpo de tu pregunta. Saludos.